# Why Ubuntu 12.04 can not copy a file from my laptop to a USB disk?

Tags: 12.10, usb

I just downloaded an Ubuntu 12.10 iso to update my operating system. But when I copy this file to the usb(h:/), it doesn't work. The copy one in the USB is "0kb".

It make me feel awful, if the size is limited? When the file is too big(700mb and more), it may doesn't work? I am a newer, hope you answer. Many thanks.

ps:you also can give me a email (mine is :smq806@gmail.com)

Thank you!

Comment: Quite bad grammar. I will provide an answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to download the full 12.10 ISO to upgrade your system.

First of all, type `update-manager -d` in a terminal.

Then click "Settings" on the bottom-left corner.

Go to "updates" tab and change the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:" to "For any new version".

Then exit the window and click "Check" in the main Update Manager window.

There should be a message saying that "New Ubuntu Release '12.10' is available". Click "Upgrade".

A window should appear telling you about the release. Then click "Upgrade".

Follow the on-screen instructions and that is it!

Comment: great！！thank you that you can reply me so speed, i 'll try of this.

Comment: Please don't mark an answer as "accepted" unless it actually solves your problem. We're happy to wait a few days if necessary.

Comment: I do agree also. Anyway this is community wiki so I don't get any reps added.